# Длина слайда с видео в HTML jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Адаптирую слайдер для галереи. В прокрутке идут картинки и видео. Таймер смены слайдов задается по классу. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы при появлении видео, время показа было либо равным длине видео и потом продолжалась дальше прокрутка, либо хотябы для слайдов с видео задать свой таймер показа. Просьба не смеяться и не мудрить - супер начальный уровень, пытаюсь разобраться :) лучше грамотный совет или помощь :)

```js
 var base = this;
    base.$el = $(el);
    base.el = el;
    base.TotalObjects = base.$el.children('.slideobject').length;
    base.CurrentObject = 1; 
    base.LoopTimer = null; 
    base.AutoChange = false;
    

    
    base.init = function() {
      base.options = $.extend($.SlideShow.defaults, options);

      if (base.options.loop) {
        base.AutoChange = true;
      }

      
      base.InitializeSlider();
      base.ShowSlide(true); 
      



      
      if (base.options.loop) {
        
        base.LoopTimer = setInterval(function() {
          base.CurrentObject++; 
          base.CurrentObject = base.GetSlideID();
          base.ShowSlide(); 
      
        
        
        }, base.options.slideDuration);
        
      }
       
      
      
    };
```

```html
 <div id="holder">
            <div id="SlideShow">
                <!-- Slide Images -->
                <img src="1.jpg" class="slideobject" />
                <img src="2.jpg" class="slideobject" />
                <img src="3.jpg" class="slideobject" />
                <div class="slideobject">
                    <!--<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="1.mp4;autoplay=1&mute=1" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen ></iframe>-->
                    <video  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen autoplay muted>
                    <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
                <!-- Descriptions for Slides -->
                <div id="slide1" class="caption">This is the description for the first slide. <a href="#">Example of a link.</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Load the SlideShow
                $('#SlideShow').SlideShow({
                  slideDuration: 5000,
                  transSpeed: 300,
                  loop: true,
                  infobar: false
                });
            });
        </script>
```